# To retrieve content from xml file and filter based on the checkbox checked

Tags: c#, jquery, xml, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-xml

Can anyone help me in coding my task.
My xml contains tags with the div defined in it to define for providing the external styles to the content and below is my xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<content>
<studies>
<heading><div class="head">XSLO</div></heading>
<industry><div class="indus">Environment</div></industry>
<product><div class="prod">Phone</div></product>
<description><div class="text">It provides a user fiendly enivironment and makes the GUI interface more reliable and compatable</div></description>
</studies>
<studies>
<heading><div class="head">Hotel Management</div></heading>
<industry><div class="indus">Hotel</div></industry>
<product><div class="prod">Hobbyist</div></product>
<description><div class="text">Customer relationship and quality is very important .Timing is also keeps up</div></description>
</studies>
<checks>
<div class="check_indus">
<div class="check_head">Industry</div>
<Environmental><input type="checkbox">Environment</input></Environmental>
<Hotel><input type="checkbox">Hotel</input></Hotel>
</div>
<div class="check_prod">
<div class="check_head">Product</div>
<Phone><input type="checkbox">Phone</input></Phone>
<Hobbyist><input type="checkbox">Hobbyist</input></Hobbyist>
</checks>
</content>
```

The above is my xml file. Now the operation to be performed is whenever we check one or more checkboxes the content under the studies tag should check with the industry and product tag and display accordingly. Can anyone please help me in coding in ASP.NET MVC 4.
It can be done by coding in view page or by querying in model class also.. Answers are most expected Kindly help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI that isn't valid XML. You need to encode the HTML within the nodes.

Comment: The HTML needs to be placed within `<![CDATA[]]>` sections. You also have invalid start/end tags for example: `<Environmetal></Environmental>` and `<Phone></phone>`. Start by fixing your XML, then attempt to solve your problem yourself first. If you're still having problems, then come back.